# Object extraction using color separation in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction

Hi all I am developing an application where in i'm extracting red colored apple from the image. I have thresholded the image `[cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(160,100,40), cvScalar(180,256,256), imgThresh);]` so that i'm able to get a binary mask of the apple. How can i combine that mask along with the original image, so that i will extract only the apple part from the original image...?

Answer (score 0):

if your image is in HSV color Model try to convert it to RGB and than split it in 3 matrix R, G and B and run the threshold only on R channel you kann use the threshold (use the threshold Binray) result as mask with the copyTo. I hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Mat::copyTo()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-copyto):

```
inputMat.copyTo(outputMat, maskMat);
```